# How to align items horizontally within a flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a really simple nav menu, with the links all in a row spaced evenly.
I have placed them in a flexbox which gives the nice justified effect, but all the elements refuse to line up horizontally.
Here is my code:

```
    #inline {
  display: flex;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
#inline div {
  height: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.smlBox {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 17px 0px 17px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
}
```

#inline is applied to the parent container, and .smlBox is applied to each nav element, which is just a div containing a hyperlink.
And this is what I get:
[image]

Can someone please advise how to get these elements ACTUALLY aligned? The other align-items options don't help either.
Here is the HTML markup as well, sorry for not including it earlier:

```
<div id="inline">
          <div class="smlBox" style="background-color: #2997d6;"><a href="#pricing" style="color:#1075b0;color:white"><strong>Register Now!</strong></a></div>
  <div class="smlBox" style="background-color: #2997d6;"><a href="#audience" style="color:#1075b0;color:white"><strong>Audience and Benefits</strong></a></div>
  <div class="smlBox" style="background-color: #2997d6;"><a href="#inspired" style="color:#1075b0;color:white"><strong>Why Inspired?</strong></a></div>
    <div class="smlBox" style="background-color: #2997d6;"><a href="#coverage" style="color:#1075b0;color:white"><strong>Typical Coverage</strong></a></div>
      <div class="smlBox" style="background-color: #2997d6;"><a href="#contact" style="color:#1075b0;color:white"><strong>Contact Us</strong></a></div></div>
```

I know it's very messy but I am working on SquareSpace which is a huge pain for handling styles and classes in their markdown blocks.

Comment: have you tried `flex-direction: row;` ?

Comment: Also, could you share your markup so that we could add a code snippet?

Comment: can you add your HTML to your Question? Your CSS together with the description is fine. There might be something wrong in the html order or with the  width of your parent container vs the with of your elements caused by the Text in your nav-Divs

Comment: @Wali Waqar flex-direction: row is the initial value so that should not be causing any problems as long as no other orientation was specified

Comment: See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Comment: I have edited my post to add the HTML markup, sorry for not including it earlier.

Comment: I've tried flex-direction: row; it makes no difference whatsoever to the alignment

Answer (score 2):

do you want like this maybe ?(See in full screen)

```css
    #inline {
  display: table;
  border: solid 1px grey;
  width:100%;
}
#inline div {
  display: flex;
   align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.smlBox {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  font-family: Century Gothic, sans-serif;
  font-size: .9em;
  margin: 17px 0px 17px 0px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7px 17px 7px 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="inline">
  <div>
    <a class="smlBox">Register Now!</a>
    <a class="smlBox">Audience and Benefits</a>
    <a class="smlBox">Why Inspired?</a>
    <a class="smlBox">Typocal Coverage</a>
    <a class="smlBox">Contact US</a>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. Yes I am considering the table layout if I cannot figure this flexbox thing out. Thanks for that suggestion